# I want to make a tasbeeh counter in flutter, button image is not maintaining its position when screen size is changing

Tags: flutter, media-queries, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to use media query not static height. So what happened is that when screen size changes the button goes up and down. I want to fit button in a specific place so it does not move even when screen size changes.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

```
//Currently my code looks like this    

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TasbeehMainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TasbeehMainScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TasbeehMainScreen> createState() => _TasbeehMainScreenState();
}

class _TasbeehMainScreenState extends State<TasbeehMainScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height;
    final width = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;

    return  Scaffold(
      body: Container(
         decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          // image: DecorationImage(
          //   image: AssetImage('assets/blackbg.png', ),
          //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
          // ),
          
        ),

        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
         Center(child: Image.asset('assets/images/counter.png',height: height*0.8, width: width*0.8,)),

           Positioned(
              bottom: height*0.18, 
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                
                },
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/button.png', height:height*0.2, width:width*0.2),
              ),
            ),

              ],
            )


          
          ],
        ),
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I answered a similar question days ago regarding mapping images to trigger callbacks and I think it would be a solution to your problem.

You can use [flutter_image_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_map) which has a [ROI selection tool](https://github.com/itzMeerkat/flutter_image_map/blob/master/index.html) that is in its repository. Once you've mapped everything just follow the [example](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_map/example) where you will be implementing the onPress callbacks depending on the region inside the image.

Comment: this is helpful. I want the value of my counter to be appear at one position, now flutter_image_map can not be used for text , so what can I do?

Comment: That is a separate question, and for that I would prefer using canvas. I believe the answer that I gave answers your current question, if so please accept it as the answer.